# Page Template does not display in drop down menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to PHP and I made my first custom page template using the Genesis framework.

I've created a theme child to the main parent Genesis, it is active and recognizable as the child, there are no errors on the dashboard of the themes.

The problem is straight forward, when I place the template in the parent directory, no problem, it is displayed in the drop down menu of the page template selection when creating a new page, however, when I place it in the child theme's dir, it does now show.

I tried to copy index.php to the child dir but no go, it only shows when it's in the parent's.

I've looked everywhere, and having a problem which I think is sourced through the method of wordpress looking for theme templates only on the parent's dir and excluding the child.

Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated.

there's the code for the template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">


        <?php if ( have_rows('about') ):

            while ( have_rows('about') ): the_row(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_sub_field('content_area'); ?></h2>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </article><!-- #post-## -->



    <?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will works

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name:New template name
*/
get_header();?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">


        <?php if ( have_rows('about') ):

            while ( have_rows('about') ): the_row(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_sub_field('content_area'); ?></h2>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </article><!-- #post-## -->



    <?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->

</div><!-- .content-area -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: I already put the comment for the template name but mistakably left it out of the code, I re edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it is working in my child genesis theme

```
 <?php
    /*
      Template Name: Template Nmae
    */
    ?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">


            <?php if ( have_rows('about') ):

                while ( have_rows('about') ): the_row(); ?>

            <h2><?php the_sub_field('content_area'); ?></h2>

            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        </article><!-- #post-## -->



        <?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->

    </div><!-- .content-area -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```